# Can't figure out getch()

Tags: c, input, switch-statement, enter, getch

im trying for hours to figure out what I'm doing wrong but can't seem to find a solution. I want to use getch() so I don't have to put enter to pass the input to a variable. Somehow i still have to press `ENTER` Here the code:

````
#include "open_txt.h"

struct daten {
    char *name[50][100];
    char *adress[50][100];
    char *birthday[50][100];
}data;

int main (){
    
    printf("\n\n\tContacts\n\n");

    printf("Main menu: \n\n");

    printf("1. Add contact\n");
    printf("2. Edit contact\n");
    printf("3. Search contact\n");

    /*char *filename;
    filename = "Adressbuch.txt";
    int c = fopen("Adressbuch.txt", "w");*/


    int ui;
    ui = getchar();


    switch(ui){

        case '1':
            printf("\n\n\tADD CONTACT\n\n");
            break;
        case '2':
            printf("\n\nEDIT CONTACT\n\n");
            break;
        case '3':
            printf("\n\nSEARCH CONTACT\n\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("That's not an option!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `getch` is not a standard C function.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with complete code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean just remove a few lines. The [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) should be a small, **complete** example that can be copied, compiled just as it is, and run to repeat the problem you are having - needing to press <Enter> after `getch()`.

Comment: Which platform are you working on (Windows vs non-Windows, mainly)?  What's in `open_txt.h`?  Please reread the bit about 'minimal' in the discussion of MRE.  Why does your minimal code require the opening of the address book file?  Why does it require the `struct daten` definition?

Comment: Your design of the structure is dubious.  A 2D array containing 5,000 pointers is a weird construct.  You should probably be using `struct daten { char name[100]; char adress[100]; char birthday[100]; }data;` and then creating an array of fifty of those structures.  What you've got is practically unusable, as well as irrelevant to the MRE.